# How to sort by number

Tags: sort

I have to sort my results by number:

```
<ul>
 <?php $productTerms = get_terms('prezzoceste', array('hide_empty' => 0, 'orderby' => 'ASC', 'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC', ));
foreach($productTerms as $productTerm) :
?>
<li>
<i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $productTerm->slug, $productTerm->taxonomy ); ?>"><?php echo $productTerm->name; ?> <span>(<?php echo $productTerm->count; ?>)</span></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pre 4.5.0 code which will eventually be depricated. Try this.

```
$productTerms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'prezzoceste',
    'hide_empty' => false,
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    'meta_key' => '_price', //The price Meta Key
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
) );
```

Check [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) for more accepted arguments.